# MySQL select unique record that matches value

Tags: mysql

I've been cracking my head for a long time and i'm not going to fix it myself so i hope i can get some help here, this is really appreciated.

My issue is the following:

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_status_id = '0' ORDER BY order_id DESC
```

This shows all the records with the value 0. This represents orders that have not been finished yet.

**What I really want is orders which are not finished where the `email` in the order has *no* other finished orders**

The problem is that in the output list there are lots of records that also have order_status_id = 1 (orders finished).

I need a query that combines the order_status_id 0 AND 1, but if there is a record that has the same email address (order_email) with order_status_id = 1, i dont want to show it.

If that works i have a clean list with all the orders that are unfinished so i can email the customers with a discount coupon.

Thanks so much for the help and i need to clairy things i would be glad to do so of course.

The actual database is a little bit more complex but in the basics the above problem would be a huge timesaver for me.

Kind regards,

Fixed:

select t1.*
from oc_order t1
left join oc_order t2 on t2.email = t1.email and t2.order_status_id='3' 
where t1.order_status_id='0'
and t2.order_status_id is null
ORDER BY `t1`.`order_id` DESC

Comment: group by, sum(finished) < 1

Comment: I didn't get a single point what are you trying to say and to do

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - sorry you've been downvoted, seems rather harsh as the question is fine.

Comment: @PaulDixon this question is regularly asked and answered on SO. The OP could have done some searching.

Comment: I have edited the opening post with the actual query... i hope this is more specific? Thanks for the amazing fast response. Just wow.

Comment: @Shadow: it looks like the example you give has to do with 2 tables, mine are all in 1 table...

Comment: It's hard to describe this sort of problem in a way that would allow those answers to found. This got 4 downvotes and 2 close votes before you linked to a related question. *Your* action is helpful, the other actions are not.

Comment: @Rayalist no, the duplicate topic is about a single table. I made sure that I find such a question in order to not have the objection you have raised.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it - the inner query is giving you a list of email addresses with finished=1, that result is used to *exclude* those emails from the outer result...

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
   WHERE email NOT IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT email FROM mytable WHERE finished=1
   )
```

Comment: Your answer is right but I think what the OP means is not excluding these emails but only showing them for the first unfinished order. The OP would have to confirm and be more specific, but a simple distinct or group by would work

Comment: Question did originally have sample data, but now removed! Still this illustrates the general technique of getting non-grouped rows based on grouped criteria

Comment: Ok. Haven't checked the edits :)

Comment: @VincentTeyssier I think the OP's edits made the question more confusing.